# Android - changing textview from other activity

Tags: android, android-activity

I'm quite new to programming.

I'm trying to make a simple app with two activities, where the second activity can change the text of the first. I know it can be done using intents, but I was wondering if there is a more direct way of doing it, for example using the second activity to call a function from the first activity?

Here's the code I have so far:

The MainActivity, which contains a TextView and a button to open the second activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

TextView textview;
Button button;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    textview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.et2);
    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b1);

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ChangeText.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPause();
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onResume();
}

public void changetext(String message) {
    textview.setText(message);
}
}
```

And the second activity, ChangeText, which contains an EditText and a button which should change the text of the TextView in MainActivity and then finish itself:

```
public class ChangeText extends Activity{

EditText edittext;
Button button;
private MainActivity mainclass;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.change_text);

    edittext = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.et2);
    button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.b2);

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String message = edittext.getText().toString(); 
        mainclass.changetext(message);
        finish();
        }
    });
}
}
```

As you can see I tried to make the app work by making a public function in MainActivity which receives a string and sets the TextView with it, and then I call this function from the ChangeText activity.

The problem: it keeps crashing! Can anyone tell me how I can make this work?

Comment: when you say it crashes - can you describe the behaviour? Is there an error?

Comment: The error is probably a NullPointer exception since the mainclass variable is never set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like I answered almost exactly the same question a week or so ago, so this is probably a duplicate, but I can't seem to find the original question.

The short answer is no - you can't call a method in an Activity from another Activity. The issue is that for normal programming purposes, only one Activity exists at a time*.

If you do something to circumvent this, then you're risking causing some major issues, including high memory usage, null pointer exceptions, etc.

The correct way to do this is indeed through the Intent system.

`*` Activities may or may not actually get destroyed when they become inactive, depending on things like how you use the back stack.
However, you should always program is if they do get destroyed when they become inactive - read, understand, and respect the Activity lifecycle.

Comment: Thanks! Then I will just do it with intents!

Answer (score 0):

For something as simple as your app, the "most direct" approach is to use the intent and startActivityForResult and them implement an onActivityResult in your main activity.

The problem you'll run into, even if you correctly pass you Activity references around is they are not guaranteed to be running at the same time.

Other ways aside from Intents, is to use a class(s) not involved with the Activity.  Either a background service or a static variable in a class that extends Application.  I rarely use Application classes anymore in favor of services and binding Activities them.

If I use an EventBus in projects, they can send Sticky events, which will hold the data until cleared.

Comment: Thanks :) In that case I will stick with intents!

Answer (score 0):

Android uses a messaging mechanism to communicate between its components. This messaging mechnism is essential to Android, so you should use it. And as you already said, the messaging is implemented by Intents. ;-)

If you want something more complex, use an EventBus or implement a your own subscribe/publish mechanism that does what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Use static variable

Example

In your MainActivity define

`public static String msg = null;`

then in your ChangeText activity assign changed text to it like

`MainActivity.msg = edittext.getText().toString();`

now in your main activity override the onResume() methode

`if(msg != null){
  textview.setText(msg);
  msg = null;
}`

Answer (score 0):

You must LocalBroadCast Manager to do so

Here is the MainActivity which has the TextView which has to updated by another Activity

```
 import android.app.Activity;
 import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
 import android.content.Context;
 import android.content.Intent;
 import android.content.IntentFilter;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.support.v4.content.LocalBroadcastManager;
 import android.view.Menu;
 import android.view.MenuItem;
 import android.view.View;
 import android.widget.TextView;




public class MainActivity extends Activity {

  TextView txt;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    txt=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt1);
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(mMessageReceiver,
            new IntentFilter("custom-event-name"));

}


private BroadcastReceiver mMessageReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String s1= intent.getStringExtra("myString");
        getIt(s1);
    }
};


@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    // Unregister since the activity is about to be closed.
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).unregisterReceiver(mMessageReceiver);
    super.onDestroy();
}


public void getIt(String s)
{

       System.out.println(s);
      txt.setText(s);

}

public void go(View view)

{

  Intent intent = new Intent(this,WriteText.class);
startActivity(intent);


}


}
```

And This is the Activity which contains the EditText which updates the TextView in the previous activity

```
 import android.app.Activity;
 import android.content.Intent;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.support.v4.content.LocalBroadcastManager;
 import android.view.Menu;
 import android.view.MenuItem;
 import android.view.View;
 import android.widget.EditText;




 public class WriteText extends Activity {

  EditText ed1;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_write_text);
    ed1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.textView);
}




 public void come(View view){


Intent intent = new Intent("custom-event-name");
intent.putExtra("myString", ed1.getText().toString());
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(intent);

 }



}
```

This Worked for me , Hope it works for you too